fundamental theorem of calculus for stochastic integral
For the Rieman integral why know by the fundamental theorem of calculus that $$\int_0^t g'(x)dx=g(t)-g(0)$$ if $g\in C^1$. Is there a similar statement for the stochastic integral? So let $(X_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ be an adapted cadlag process of finite variation and $g\in C_1(\mathbb R)$. Does
$$\int_0^1 g'(X_s)dX_s=g(X_1)-g(X_0)$$ hold? If yes, why?

No. Sanity check: take as $X$ of finite variation the "process" $X_t=\int_0^tY_s,ds,.$

Kurt G. notwithstanding, the answer is Yes (because $X$ has paths of bounded variation). Use the Riemann-Stieltjes from of the FTC, path by path.

@JohnDawkins totally right. My mistake. It is a form of the chain rule.

If you edit your question with what you have tried, it may get re-opened.
